# BLS Signature Scheme in Java: Storing and Loading Keys

Tags: java, serialization, cryptography, digital-signature, jpbc

We need a method to sign messages using signatures that are as short as possible and came across the BLS scheme, which promises rather short-ish signatures. Trying the JPBC implementation, the examples are easy to set up and run, but they lack a rather crucial part: storing and loading the private keys.

- The example from the current JPBC BLS website [1](http://gas.dia.unisa.it/projects/jpbc/schemes/ss_bls01.html#.XBpXKFWYWV4) does not contain any storage whatsoever, it just verifies a message using the instances in RAM.
- An older example from the same website [2](http://gas.dia.unisa.it/projects/jpbc/schemes/bls.html) which is no longer linked on the website but can be found using search engines refers to a `store` method which seems to have since been removed from the library in favour of an implementation that does not contain any storage capabilities.
- The `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair` instances (which are what I get from the keygen) are not serializable by themselves, neither are instances of `BLS01PublicKeyParameters` or `BLS01PrivateKeyParameters`, with the fields that contain the keys (`sk` and `pk`) being private and typed only to the `Element` interface that doesn't really say much about the contents.

As a workaround, I have implemented a store method, that (stripped of all exception handling) roughly looks like this:

```
public static void storePrivateKey(AsymmetricCipherKeyPair key, String filename)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Field f = null;
    f = key.getPrivate().getClass().getDeclaredField("sk");
    if (f != null) {
        f.setAccessible(true);
        Object fieldContent = null;
        fieldContent = f.get(key.getPrivate());
        if (fieldContent != null) {
            byte[] data = null;
            if (fieldContent instanceof ImmutableZrElement) {
                ImmutableZrElement izr = (ImmutableZrElement)fieldContent;
                data = izr.toBytes();
            }
            try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename)) {
                fos.write(data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With a similar approach for public keys. That means, I'm now down to using reflection to retrieve the contents of a private field in order to store it somewhere. That solution is obviously a hackish collection of all sorts of bad smells, but it's so far the best that I've come up with. I know that writing some bytes to disk shouldn't really be that hard, but I really can't seem to find the proper way to do this. Also, to be blunt, I'm not into crypto: I want to apply this scheme to sign and verify some messages, that is all. I understand that I should dig deeper into the math of the whole approach, but time is limited - which is why I picked a library in the first place.

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Comment: How do I properly store (and load) BLS keys in JPBC?